# deleted csv still being referenced python/datetime object

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I am really new to python and I am having trouble with my outputs. I am using Ipython to write my code as well. What I want to do is synchronize two clock times. I first open a csv with a time from one source in one column and time from another source in the other column. Once I find the difference between those values I import another csv that has all the values from the time source that was lagging and add the difference so that the lagging clock is now standard with the other. 
Problems:
1.When I switch out the first csv to calculate another time difference e.g (first csv time difference was 5 min and new csv time difference is 2 min) the outputs will have 5 min added instead of 2 min. I have attached the code so you can see.
2. I also don't know how to convert the datetime objects into time objects to get rid of the 1900-01-01. I saw forums for that but I didn't understand the code so if there is a simple way to do this I would appreciate it.

I know I am missing alot of basics but I appreciate the help!

```
import csv
from datetime import time
time_difference= open('TEST.csv')
time_difference_csv=csv.reader(time_difference)#imports csv with the two       #clock differences; e.g wall clock and scanner clock one value in each column
firstline = True
for row in time_difference_csv:
    if firstline:    #skip first line
        firstline = False
         continue
# parse the line
for row in time_difference_csv:#converts the string values of the clock    #into datetimes which allows them to be subtracted and added
    w = [[datetime.time.strptime(i[0],'%H:%M:%S')]+ [datetime.time.strptime(i[1],'%H:%M:%S')] for i in time_difference_csv]
for row in w:#gets the difference btwn the two clocks
    p= (row[1]-row[0])
for row in w:
    l= (row[1]-row[0]) + row[0]

td= open('121Times3.csv')#imports csv with the list of times from one    time source; e.g. just the scanner times
td_csv=csv.reader(td)
firstline = True

for row in td_csv:
    if firstline:    #skip first line
        firstline = False
        continue
# parse the line
for row in td_csv:
    k = [[datetime.time.strptime(i[0],'%H:%M:%S')] for i in td_csv]

for row in k:#adds the difference found earlier to all the times on the csv. Converts all the scanner times to the wall times.
    print row[0] + p
```

Output
    1900-01-01 10:37:09
    1900-01-01 11:48:54
    1900-01-01 11:19:08
    1900-01-01 10:37:09
    1900-01-01 11:48:54
    1900-01-01 11:19:08
    1900-01-01 10:37:09
    1900-01-01 11:48:54
    1900-01-01 11:19:08

Comment: some general comments: with the way your code is indented, you loop through all of the rows of the files, but then only parse the last line. intentional? also, you're not closing any of your files, which you should definitely do.

Comment: I think when I was copying it over some of the indentation got changed so I think its fine on my real one. and I also was running it through again and now the outputs are connected to the right csv's so the time differences are now correct even when I switch out the csv. I have tried to figure out what I did but I cant see the difference. Now I just need a way to get rid of the 1900-01-01 without changing too much of my code.

Comment: So I would close this question and ask another one that completely isolated the time formatting issue you are having.

Comment: actually I just tried running some more files through and now the outputs are displaying the values from the replaced second csv ( the time difference is changing but not what that difference is being added to). So how do you close the file? Also do you think it could be the referencing in the directory? Thanks

Comment: Eg `time_difference.close()`

Comment: for the second csv it is still referring to the old deleted one for the values.

Comment: I can't help you further without a reproducible example. I don't have your CSV files, so you should mock some up with the StringIO module.

Comment: And definitely fix your indentation.